# Facebook Graph API - Get first upcoming events

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, graph

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me/events?fields=name,start_time&since=now

- Event #1 (2015-12-07)
- Event #2 (2015-12-06)
- Event #3 (2015-12-05)

As you can see the events are in reverse chronological order.

This url gives me all the events in the future, but starts with the event that will happen as the last. I'm wondering if it's possible to GET all own events from Facebook but starting from the first upcoming event.

Can I change the order in which the events appear ? Because Facebook Graphs API is using paging, the first upcoming event is situated at the last page. There has to be a better way than starting from the last page and going back to the first page. (Because when I would start at the last page, then there is the possibility that there are less than 25 events on that page). //25 is the default limit for 1 page

This is the result I would like to have:

- Event #1 (2015-12-05)
- Event #2 (2015-12-06)
- Event #3 (2015-12-07)

To make this long story short: I would like to obtain the first upcoming events and when I go to the next page, then I would like to get the next events.

I hope you can understand what I mean, IF NOT, please ask me some extra explanation

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You need to do this on your side

Comment: The problem is that facebook uses paging. And in my solution, it's not possible to load more than 1000 events at once.

Comment: You can sort the events data based on time, that you fetched from Facebook Events. Alternatively, you can also give a try by using `desc=start_time` parameter in your Graph API